# UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died and Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, teardown

When I execute a test suite, tearDown() method fails randomly and all tests below it gets skipped. Below are the details. SCREENSHOT ATTACHED.

TESTNG trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died. Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '61506a4624b13675f24581e453592342b7485d71', time: '2015-06-04 10:22:50' System info: host: 'W7-VDI-WDW704', ip: '10.207.15.35', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_152' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

LOG:

```
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@12c7a01b 
Oct 09, 2018 4:03:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it
org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils$ProcessStillAliveException: Timeout waiting for process to die at org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils.waitForProcessDeath(ProcessUtils.java:67) at (...)

Suite Total tests run: 196, Failures: 4, Skips: 175 Configuration Failures: 176, Skips: 175
```

[image]

- Chrome version: Version 69.0.3497.100
- Chromedriver: ChromeDriver 2.42**

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died
.
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@12c7a01b Oct 09, 2018 4:03:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to kill the **WebBrowser** i.e. **RemoteWebDriver**.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

As per the discussion [On Windows, RemoteWebDriver.quit() is always destroying forcefully?](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/614) this issue was evident in pre **Selenium v2.45.0** builds where @timja2 mentioned in his [comment](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/614#issuecomment-110145658) that:

> it expected to always destroy harder on Windows

This fix was incorporated through [commit 7a5e890](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/7a5e890ac2d37c76ac972ee22cfbc8aa89f83742) and was expected to be available from **Selenium v2.53.1** onwards.

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  minimum **Version 2.53.1** or current level of [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).